# Sending null parameter to querystring Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012-express

I have the following problem. I want to send null value to Stored Procedure with querystringparameter.

This is my Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetAllProducts
 @catID int = null,
 @subcatID int = null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Products WHERE
    ((@catID is null) OR (category_id = @catID))
    AND ((@subcatID is null) OR (subcategory_id = @subcatID))
END
```

it is working when i am testing with following queries as exactly how i want

```
spGetAllProducts null, '3'
spGetAllProducts '8', null
spGetAllProducts '8', '3'
spGetAllProducts null, null
```

but when i am trying to send null value with queryparameter it is not working

here is my sqldatasource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringReviewDB %>" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="spGetAllProducts">

    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Direction="Input" Name="catID" QueryStringField="catID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Direction="Input" Name="subcatID" QueryStringField="subcatID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
    </SelectParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When i am sending the query like this

```
http://localhost:50693/TreeViews.aspx?catID=8&subcatID=3
```

it is working but when i am sending the following query it is not working

```
http://localhost:50693/TreeViews.aspx?catID=8&subcatID=
```

Thx from now

Comment: As @LearningAsp answered, your second query equal to the following: `spGetAllProducts '8', ''`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

`CREATE PROCEDURE spGetAllProducts
 @catID int = null,
 @subcatID int = null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Products WHERE
    ((@catID  '') OR (category_id = @catID))
    AND ((@subcatID = '') OR (subcategory_id = @subcatID))
END`

I think as stored procedure takes it as empty string not as null ,I had similar problem and it worked for me

Comment: thx i changed my stored procedure now when i am sending '0' value it is working

Comment: ok ,then check you parameter while sending to stored procedure ,if it is "" i.e. empty string then replace it with 0